# Предлог ЗА

Tags: предлоги

Господа филологи, такой вопрос. Возник спор.
Если сидя в машине, сказать водителю "остановите за "Жигули" (допустим, "Жигули стот у обочины), где он должен остановиться согласно правилам использования предлога ЗА? Проехав стоящую машину и перед ней или за ней следом?

Comment: Не за "Жигули", а за "Жигулями". И ещё вопрос, с прописной ли... Вот это языковой вопрос. А ваш – не языковой. Можно понять как угодно: то ли проехать, то ли за ней следом.

Comment: Ваше замечание принято :) 
Вы правы, понять можно как угодно :) А вот КАК правильно с точки зрения употребления этого предлога?

Comment: Не могу согласиться. Вопрос вполне нормальный, даже интересный,  а вот Ваш ответ не соответствует формату ресурса.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь имеет место семантическая неоднозначность. Предлог "ЗА" может означать и "в точке после [проезда] объекта" и "следом за объектом (в цепочке или очереди)". Решать надо по контексту. Как понимают водители - это надо эксперимент ставить ))).

Если уж совсем никак, то выбирайте другой вариант "перед машиной" или "после машины". Здесь меньше шансов, что поймут неправильно, хотя исключить все равно нельзя.

Да, уже сказали, "Жигули"склоняется, это название русское (обрусевшее), множественное число - по названию природного объекта. Не надо смешивать с Тбилиси и т. п.

Answer (score 0):

С точки зрения языка корректны следующие употребления:

- остановите за автомобилем "Жигули"
- остановите за "Жигулями"

А вот понять можно и так и так.

Если абстрактно рассматривать автомобиль, стоящий у обочины - то у него есть передняя часть и задняя часть, а "за автомобилем" - это разумеется после задней части автомобиля.

С другой стороны вы коммуницируете с водителем, он едет по дороге и если рассматривать с его точки - то по направлению движения машины водителя находится некий объект (автомобиль "Жигули") и вы просите остановить за этим объектом, то есть "проехать вперёд пока автомобиль Жигули не останется позади нас".

Это чисто коммуникационная проблема, можно действительно и так и так понять.

Могу вам рассказать, как в моей лично практике водители воспринимают подобные фразы "остановить за..." -- но это очень индивидуально и спорно: всегда найдутся люди, у которых другой опыт.

Чисто к сведению: как мне кажется, водители обычно проезжают вперёд пока ориентир не останется позади нашей машины.